# unable to load scripts from assets 'index.android.bundle' on real device

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build.gradle

This issue is a bit popular , however I can't see the available solutions fit with me ,

running this command , did not work for me

> react-native bundle --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output index.android.bundle

it's a screenshot of the issue

[image]

my react native version is : 0.58.5

some important configs inside build.gradle (in project level)

```
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "27.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 28
    targetSdkVersion = 27
    supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
}
```

if you need more info , please tell me

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that the path has an asset. `android/app/src/main/assets`
   If the folder assets doesn’t exist then create the assets directory
   there.
2. If it exists then delete two files viz `index.android.bundle` and
   `index.android.bundle.meta`
3. Then return to the root project directory and execute the command.

   ```
   cd android &&
   ./gradlew clean
   ```
4. Go back to the root directory and run the command if you have one
   `index.js` file.

`react-native bundle --platform android --dev false
    --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest
    android/app/src/main/res`

5. If you have two `index.js` files, replace them and run them twice. // index.android.js and index.ios.js

   `index`.js => `index.android.js` or `index.ios.js`